# Travelling inside Schengen area after the visa expires-before the residence permit is issued?

Tags: visas, schengen, residency

I have a Turkish passport and have been studying in Poland for a semester. My visa ends in two weeks and to be able to stay and study one more semester legally in Poland, I will apply for a residence permit. It is said that residence permit procedure can take up to 2 months starting from the date of application.

The thing is, I was planning to visit other countries inside of the Schengen area. Can I still leave the country after my visa expires and before the residence permit is issued? I plan to travel only for a few days and via bus. Is it too risky?

I have travelled a month ago via car while my passport was on me and no one asked me if I had one. I know it's always safer to wait but I have an appointment to see a professor so I'd prefer not to cancel it.

Comment: The fact that you were not controlled doesn't mean you were allowed to travel. The Schengen area has adopted unified **external** border controls and reduced **internal** border controls because they trust people who are in to abide by the terms of their residency status.

Comment: `I will apply for a residence permit` Why were you waiting till now ?? `no one asked me if I had one` Don't assume you willn't be asked. `but I have an appointment to see a professor` Why leave everything to the last moment.

Comment: I suppose you have more problems than not just being able to go to other Schengen countries. When done in Poland, applications for a temporary residence permit (or extensions thereof) must be made at least two months before the current admission expires, so that the application can be completed during your previously admitted period of stay. I would not be surprised if you have to leave the Schengen area completely when your current visa expires, even if you have an ongoing application for a residence permit.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it deals with a mainly Expat kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Legally speaking your visa is valid as long as the application for the residence permit is being processed. If you want to travel before then, you need to visit your local foreigners' police department and get a "temporary Schengen visa" which would be valid for 2-3 months and allow you to travel outside of Poland.

Source: knowledge of procedure in the neighboring Czech Republic.